# Tracking ID in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a SAS question. I have a dataset containing ID and year. I want to create the dummyvariables "2011" and "2012" that should take on the value 1 if the ID has an observation in the given year and 0 otherwise. Eg. ID 2 should have 2011=1 and 2012=0, since the ID only has an observation for 2011.

```
ID   Year   2011   2012
1    2011     1      1 
1    2012     1      1
2    2011     1      0
3    2012     0      1
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, `2011` or `2012` are not valid names for SAS variables. SAS variables must start with a letter or an underscore (e.g., `_2011`).

If you really need to, you can get around that limitation by setting the system option `validvarname=any` and surrounding your 'invalid' variable names with single quotes and appending an `n`.

This would do what you want:

```
data have;
infile datalines;
input ID year;
datalines;
1 2011
1 2012
2 2011
3 2012
;
run;

options validvarname=ANY;
proc sql;
create table want as
select ID
      ,year
      ,exists(select * from have b where year=2011 and a.id=b.id) as '2011'n
      ,exists(select * from have b where year=2012 and a.id=b.id) as '2012'n
from have a
;
quit;
```

Comment: @user2877959 At least my SAS requires a dot after n : "as '2011'n. " to function correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't make the program code work with my dataset. Maybe there is a way around it, but I'm not familiar with the proc sql syntax.

What I have is a large dataset containing unique ID's and a bunch of variables for each year in a time series. Some ID's are present throughout the entire timeseries, some new ID's are added and some old ID's are removed. I want to know which ID's are new and which are removed in any given year. Do you have any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: @user2877959 When I copy-paste the code I get "ERROR: The value 2011 is not a valid SAS name."

Comment: @pinegulf alright I think I understand what the problem is. I added a line to my code that should fix it for you. What I do find surprising is that it works if you add a dot like you explained.

Comment: @ThomasChristensen as this code works for the sample you have provided, I would need to understand how your actual data is different from that sample and how you attempted to translate that solution to that data in order to understand what your problem is. Maybe you can start a new question by posting a sample dataset that more resembles your actual data (keeping it simple as possible though), post what code you tried based on the above answer and we'll see if we can help further.

Comment: @user2877959 I made a repost at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46406126/tracking-id-in-sas