# Tracking ID in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a SAS question. I have a large dataset containing unique ID's and a bunch of variables for each year in a time series. Some ID's are present throughout the entire timeseries, some new ID's are added and some old ID's are removed.

```
ID    Year    Var3    Var4
1     2015    500     200
1     2016    600     300
1     2017    800     100
2     2016    200     100
2     2017    100     204
3     2015    560     969
3     2016    456     768
4     2015    543     679
4     2017    765     534
```

As can be seen from the table above, ID 1 is present in all three years (2015-2017), ID 2 is present from 2016 and onwards, ID 3 is removed in 2017 and ID 4 is present in 2015, removed in 2016 and then present again in 2017.

I would like to know which ID's are new and which are removed in any given year, whilst keeping all the data. Eg. a new table with indicators for which ID's are new and which are removed. Furthermore, it would be nice to get a frequency of how many ID' are added/removed in a given year and the sum og their "Var3" and "Var4". Do you have any suggestions how to do that?

************* UPDATE ******************

Okay, so I tried the following program:

```
**** Addition to suggested code ****;
options validvarname=any;

proc sql noprint;
create table years as
select distinct year
from have;

create table ids as
select distinct id
from have;

create table all_id_years as
select a.id,  b.year
from ids as a,
years as b
order by id, year;

create table indicators as
select coalesce(a.id,b.id) as id,
coalesce(a.year,b.year) as year,
coalesce(a.id/a.id,0) as indicator
from have as a
full join
all_id_years as b
on a.id = b.id
and a.year = b.year
order by id, year
;
quit;
```

Now this will provide me with a table that only contains the ID's that are new in 2017:

```
data new_in_17;
set indicators;
where ('2016'n=0) and ('2017'n=1);
run;
```

I can now merge this table to add var3 and var4:

```
data new17;
merge new_in_17(in=x1) have(in=x2);
by id;
if x1=x2;
run;
```

Now I can find the frequence of new ID's in 2017 and the sum of var3 and var4:

```
proc means data=new17 noprint;
var var3 var4;
where year in (2017);
output out=sum_var_freq_new sum(var3)=sum_var3 sum(var4)=sum_var4;
run;
```

This gives me the output I need. However, I would like the equivalent output for the ID's that are "gone" between 2016 and 2017 which can be made from:

```
data gone_in_17;
set indicators;
where ('2016'n=1) and ('2017'n=0);
run;

data gone17;
merge gone_in_17(in=x1) have(in=x2);
by id;
if x1=x2;
run;

proc means data=gone17 noprint;
var var3 var4;
where year in (2016);
output out=sum_var_freq_gone sum(var3)=sum_var3 sum(var4)=sum_var4;
run;
```

The end result should be a combination of the two tables "sum_var_freq_new" and "sum_var_freq_gone" into one table. Furthermore, I need this table for every new year, so my current approach is very inefficient. Do you guys have any suggestions how to achieve this efficiently?

Comment: What is the desired output? Do you want a new table with indicators of which years each ID is present? Something else?

Comment: @DomPazz: yes, a new table with indicators would be great. Furthermore, it would be nice to get a frequence of how many ID' are added/removed in a given year and the sum og their "Var3" and "Var4".

Comment: You should also post what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from a different sample, you didn't provide much extra info from your previous question in order to understand what was lacking in the previous answer.

To build on the latter though, you could use a macro do loop to dynamically account for the distinct `year` values present in your dataset.

```
data have;
infile datalines;
input ID year var3 var4;
datalines;
1 2015 500 200
1 2016 600 300
1 2017 800 100
2 2016 200 100
2 2017 100 204
3 2015 560 969
3 2016 456 768
4 2015 543 679
4 2017 765 534
;
run;

proc sql noprint;
select distinct year
into :year1-
from have
;
quit;
%macro doWant;
  proc sql;
  create table want as
  select distinct ID
%let i=1;
%do %while(%symexist(year&i.));
        ,exists(select * from have b where year=&&year&i.. and a.id=b.id) as "&&year&i.."n
  %let i=%eval(&i.+1);
%end;
  from have a
  ;
quit;
%mend;
%doWant;
```

This will produce the following result:

```
ID  2015 2016 2017
-----------------
1   1    1    1
2   0    1    1
3   1    1    0
4   1    0    1
```

Comment: This will definitely work, but I think it will be woefully inefficient for a large data set

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more efficient way of doing this and also giving you the summary values.

First a little SQL magic.  Create the cross product of years and IDs, then join that to the table you have to create an indicator;

```
proc sql noprint;
/*All Years*/
create table years as
select distinct year
    from have;

/*All IDS*/
create table ids as
select distinct id
    from have;

/*All combinations of ID/year*/
create table all_id_years as
select a.id,  b.year
    from ids as a,
         years as b
    order by id, year;

/*Original data with rows added for missing years.  Indicator=1 if it*/
/*existed prior, 0 if not.*/
create table indicators as
select coalesce(a.id,b.id) as id,
       coalesce(a.year,b.year) as year,
       coalesce(a.id/a.id,0) as indicator
    from have as a
      full join
         all_id_years as b
      on a.id = b.id
       and a.year = b.year
    order by id, year
    ;
quit;
```

Now transpose that.

```
proc transpose data=indicators out=indicators(drop=_name_);
by id;
id year;
var indicator;
run;
```

Create the sums.  You could also add other summary stats if you wanted here:

```
proc summary data=have;
by id;
var var3 var4;
output out=summary sum=;
run;
```

Merge the indicators and the summary values:

```
data want;
merge indicators summary(keep=id var3 var4);
by id;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

This is a great starting point! However, it needs a little adjustment for my need. I would like a table for each new timeperiod/year containing the frequency of ID's that had indicator=0 in timeperiod t-1 and indicator=1 in timeperiod t (meaning that the id was inactive in t-1 and active in t. Hence, the id is "new" in t). 

Likewise, i want the frequency of ID's that had indicator=1 in timeperiod t-1 and indicator=0 in timeperiod t (meaning that the id was active in t-1 and inactive in t. Hence, the id is "gone" in t).

Comment: Furthermore, I need to know the sum of var3 and var4 for all ID's that are "new" and "gone" in each year.

Comment: I edited an update into my initial post. Hopefully this will give a better understanding of my problem :)